# Slow Page Loading Issue With Latest Kendo Release

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik

We upgraded the Telerik Kendo library in our web application last week from V2015.2.902 to V2016.1.112.  Since then, we've noticed that the pages that use Kendo take a very long time to load (30 seconds up to 2 minutes).  I used some tools to analyze the http traffic, and they appear to take so long because the browser is downloading the full Kendo js file (5mb) every time a page is accessed.  Once it loads the first time, postbacks are near-instant and the issue goes away.  But once you browse away and back, or restart the browser, its back to slow-loading again.
The only other thing we changed was switching from the full kendo library to the minified one.  And yes, we did update all references in our pages to point to the minified version.  Even if it does have to load the Kendo file each time, I wouldn't think a 5mb file would take a minute or two to download.

Here is my reference.  I've confirmed the path is correct and the file is there.  I'm testing in IE11.

```
<script src="Kendo/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

Has anyone had this happen?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, I have a similar issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which Kendo libraries are you using? You can always use their CDN which should help with the speed. If you are testing in chrome with an unminified js file from Kendo then it is also possible that it will run slower. I suggest if your not going to use their CDN then try downloading the minified files.

Comment: I pretty much have all the libraries included in the project.  I'm not referencing their CDN...I was hoping to avoid that.  I have/am using the minified files already.  I wasn't before, but now we are.

Comment: Can you show a quick code sample of your index page where your references are? Are you referencing the all.min that they usually provide, or are you referencing multiple different files? Also which browser are you testing in?

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: 5mb will definitely slow things down but not by a minute, were talking maybe 30 seconds. A few things you could try are rolling back a version in Kendo, or try minifying all of your files. Before you roll back I suggest trying the CDN just for testing to see if that speeds up performance at all. If it is still slow with the CDN then the issue isn't with Kendo.